# How use id in URL axios post method react?

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

I tried to create an app for management, but in the cycle of my app, I have to use a process for creating a session.

In that, I create a localization, but afterwards, I need to create a session in that location.

For that, I need to pass the id of the localization in the post request (api/localisations/{localisation_id}/sessions), but I don't know how to do that.

When I create a session, I have this:

```
AddLocalisations (localisations) {
axios.request({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/localisations/',
  data: localisations,

}).catch(err => console.log(err))
}

onSubmit (event) {
const newLocalisations = {
  name: this.refs.name.value,
  address: this.refs.address.value,
  phone: this.refs.phone.value,

}
this.AddLocalisations(newLocalisations)
event.preventDefault(
  this.props.history.push('/AddSessions'),
)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
 AddLocalisations = (localisation_id, localisations) => {
  let url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/localisations/" +localisation_id "/sessions"; 
  let data = {localisations };
  axios.post(url, data).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

if it's not working then  use  `"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8000",` in your package.json file in your project.
 and now your url  is  `let url = "/api/localisations/" +localisation_id "/sessions";`

Answer (score 1):

You can do in below way. When you call AddLocalisations pass localisation_id to it as a parameter and in function append it to url variable

```
 AddLocalisations (localisation_id, localisations) {
      let url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/localisations/${localisation_id}/sessions`; //template literals
      axios.request({
          method: 'post',
          url: url,
          data: localisations,
          }).catch(err => console.log(err))
     }
```

Comment: you think i need to do this when i create a localisation ? or a session ? For the loc it's the code in my question and for the session actually i use this but the id is fix...     `axios.request({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/localisations/2/sessions',
      data: sessions,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json' , 'Accept': 'application/json'}

    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  }`

Comment: My solution is for localisation. You can pass localisation id to the handler function and append it to the url

Comment: when i do this i have this error :                                                                                   Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/localisations/[object%20Object]/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: You have to pass localisation id to this.AddLocalisations(localisation_id, newLocalisations) in onSubmit

Comment: I follow your instructions ( sorry i'm a beginner) but now i have this error ... : Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/AddLocalisations?name=Thibaut+Monsegu&address=46+rue+charles+lorilleux&phone=634266529
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: or else tel me from where do you get the localisation id?

Comment: You need to pass full url http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/localisations/${localisation_id}/sessions to fullfill the request